# Logistic regression and maximum entropy

Tags: regression, logistic, classification, entropy, maximum-entropy

I have read (e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_maximum_entropy#Maximum_entropy_models)) that a (multinomial) logistic regressor corresponds to a maximum entropy classifier.

My question is, how does one end up with the formula for logistic regression starting with the maximum entropy principle?

Comment: One way is by considering the dual convex program.

Comment: Thanks @cardinal - Do you know of any sources that I can look up to learn more about the dual convex derivation?

Comment: Hi Josh. I'm not entirely sure where to best direct you off-hand. You might look in Boyd & Vandenberghe (available for free online) to start. I will hunt around here in a bit and see if I can give you a more definitive pointer. Are you familiar with convex programming?

Comment: Thanks @cardinal. I am familiar with convex programming and duality. I guess what I am looking for is: (1) the problem formulation (2) the formulation of maximum entropy (I presume as constraints), and somehow a proof that logistic regressor emerges as the optimal solution.

Comment: **Example 5.5** (*Unconstrained geometric program*) on page 254 of B&V will get you very close. With your stated background, I suspect you can take it from there. :-)

Comment: See http://www.win-vector.com/dfiles/LogisticRegressionMaxEnt.pdf  for an explanation

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; the *logistic* function can originate from an *exponential* function for different outcomes

$$p(y;x) \propto \text{exp}(f(y,x))$$

and with the normalisation using the sum $\sum_{\forall y} p(y;x)$ it becomes a logistic function

$$p(y;x) = \frac{\text{exp}(f(y,x))}{\text{other stuff}+\text{exp}(f(y,x))}$$

The connection with entropy is in the exponential function $p(y;x) \propto \text{exp}(f(y,x))$ which is similar to the [Boltzmann distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution).

---

We want to estimate a probability distribution $$\hat{f}(y|x_1,x_2) = \begin{cases}p(y;x_1,x_2) &\quad \text{if $y=1$}\\
1-p(y;x_1,x_2) &\quad \text{if $y=0$}\end{cases}$$

where $y$ is a binary outcome variable and the $x_i$ are predictors.

Say we want to find a $\hat{f}$ that maximizes the entropy

$$H = E[-\log(\hat{f}(y,x_1,x_2)]$$

where $\hat{f}(y,x_1,x_2) = \hat{f}(y;x_1,x_2)f(x_1,x_2)$

with constraints

$$E[y \cdot x_1] = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=1}^N y_j x_{1j}\\
E[y \cdot x_2] = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=1}^N y_j x_{2j}$$

where the expectations are computed based on the empirical distribution/frequency of a sample $x_{1j}$ and $x_{2j}$ of size $N$.

Then the distribution will be of the form

$$ \hat{f}(y,x_1,x_2) = \frac{1}{Z} \text{exp}\left(\alpha_1 y \cdot x_1 + \alpha_2 y \cdot x_2\right) $$

where $Z$ is a normalisation constant.

The ratio of the conditional distribution will be

$$\frac{\hat{f}(1|x_1,x_2)}{\hat{f}(0|x_1,x_2)} = \frac{\hat{f}(1,x_1,x_2)}{\hat{f}(0,x_1,x_2)} = \frac{ \text{exp}\left(\alpha_1 1 \cdot x_1 + \alpha_2 1 \cdot x_2\right)}{\text{exp}\left(\alpha_1 0 \cdot x_1 + \alpha_2 0 \cdot x_2\right)} = \text{exp}\left(\alpha_1 \cdot x_1 + \alpha_2 \cdot x_2\right) $$

Then if you take the logarithm

$$\text{log} \left( \frac{\hat{f}(1|x_1,x_2)}{\hat{f}(0|x_1,x_2)} \right) = \text{log} \left( \frac{\hat{f}(1|x_1,x_2)}{1-\hat{f}(1,x_1,x_2)} \right) = \left(\alpha_1 \cdot x_1 + \alpha_2 \cdot x_2\right) $$

you get the logit function.

The parameters $\alpha_i$ will need to be found by optimizing the entropy (and this turns out to be the same as optimizing the likelihood).