# Can we use gradient descent method in maximum entropy model?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, maximum-entropy

I see a lot of implementations use GIS or IIS to train the maximum entropy model. Can we use gradient descent method? If we can use it, why most tutorial directly tell GIS or IIS methods, but do not show the simple gradient descent method to train maximum entropy model?

As we know, softmax regression is equivalent to the maxent model, but I never heard GIS or IIS in softmax. Why? Is there a toy code use simple gradient descent method to train maxent model? I think is easy to implement a toy code, the derivation is simply compute the empirical expectation and model expectation.

Comment: Of possible interest: Malouf 2002. A comparison of algorithms for maximum entropy parameter estimation.

Comment: What is GIS? IIS? Please [edit] to clarify. Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77375/logistic-regression-and-maximum-entropy